How to use Sharp in AWS Lambda function? I keep getting errors. (node.js, for image resizing)
I added this Lambda layer to my function, which is described as follows: "This serverless application provides a Lambda Layer that includes the sharp image processing library for Node.js"
I'm now trying to run a Lambda function that uses Sharp, but I keep getting errors.
When I try to run it including an import statement, like so...
import sharp from 'sharp';
...
await sharp(inputImagePath)
    .resize(desiredWidth, desiredHeight)
    .toFile(outputImagePath);

...I get this error message:
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Could not load the \"sharp\" module using the linux-x64 runtime\nPossible solutions:\n- Ensure optional dependencies can be installed:\n    npm install --include=optional sharp\n    yarn add sharp --ignore-engines\n- Ensure your package manager supports multi-platform installation:\n    See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#cross-platform\n- Add platform-specific dependencies:\n    npm install --os=linux --cpu=x64 sharp\n- Consult the installation documentation:\n    See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Could not load the \"sharp\" module using the linux-x64 runtime",
    "Possible solutions:",
    "- Ensure optional dependencies can be installed:",
    "    npm install --include=optional sharp",
    "    yarn add sharp --ignore-engines",
    "- Ensure your package manager supports multi-platform installation:",
    "    See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#cross-platform",
    "- Add platform-specific dependencies:",
    "    npm install --os=linux --cpu=x64 sharp",
    "- Consult the installation documentation:",
    "    See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js:114:9)",
    "    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)",
    "    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)",
    "    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)",
    "    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)",
    "    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)",
    "    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:10:1)",
    "    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)",
    "    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)"
  ]
}

Then when I try to run Sharp commands without any overt import statement, it gives me "sharp is undefined" errors.
I'm just very confused because my understanding is, the Lambda layer makes it so I can use Sharp in my Lambda function? What am I missing or doing wrong here? Thanks.

UPDATE on this:
The solution was to NOT use this Lambda layer. Instead I had to package up Sharp in a zipped folder alongside my index.mjs file, and I was able to trigger it that way. There were also weird additional requirements such as, ensuring you install Sharp in the right way so that it's compatible with the AWS Lambda function code architecture you're writing in. It was a genuine slog to figure this out but if you're struggling to get that Lambda layer working, the fix for me was NOT using that Lambda layer.

which node version you used in your template?
